# Sending commands prefixed with `Shift`-`Alt` to VSCode's integrated terminal in Windows 11

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to send keyboard shortcuts prefixed with `Shift`-`Alt` to VSCode's integrated terminal in Windows 11?

I'm using [Tilish](https://github.com/jabirali/tmux-tilish), a nifty `tmux` plugin that by default uses several shortcuts prefixed with `Shift`-`Alt` (e.g. `Shift`-`Alt`-`q` to close a panel). Unfortunately, commands prefixed with `Shift`-`Alt` don't seem to get propagated to the terminal.

Ideally I'd prefer *all* input go to the terminal while my input focus is there.

Thanks!